# Multipole terms of Electrostatic energy

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential-energy, multipole-expansion

If we consider the Potential and electric field of a Dipole,
could we infer that for a dipole :

$V \propto 1/r^2$, $E \propto 1/r^3$ ,  $da \propto r^2$, then

Electrostatic potential energy should vary as $\propto 1/r^3$.

Basically I want know whether the energy term also varies as accordingly for dipole , quadrupole ..or higher-order terms?

Comment: What potential energy? Of a system of two dipoles? Or a dipole and a point charge?

Comment: Potential of a dipole and a point charge.

Comment: So then, what is the work done by the electric field of the dipole on the point charge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right but only for large distances (so the calculation is only valid for large distances)

The energy density is given by
$$ u\propto E^2\propto \frac{1}{r^6} $$
where we use the fact that for large distances, We have $$\mathbf{E}=\frac{p}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^3}(2\cos\theta\hat{r}+\sin\theta\hat{\theta})$$
$$dU\propto\frac{1}{r^4}dr$$
So you expect for the large distances we have
$$U\propto \frac{1}{r^3}$$
Note that if you integrate over whole space, you get undefined because there is a singularity at origin which implies that approximation not valid for small distance because the energy is increasing indefinitely.